# Simple json like this. creating and parsing

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to create and parse json like this

```
{
"time1": { "UserId": "Action"},
"time2": { "UserId": "Action"},
"time3": { "UserId": "Action"}
}
```

with [json-simple.jar](https://json-simple.googlecode.com/files/json-simple-1.1.1.jar)
I would like to keep on updating the json with the element `"time": { "UserId": "Action"}`

Any help ? please

Comment: Why don't you change your json to something like this?
{
"timestamps": [{"time": "1", "uid": "0", "action": "add"}, . . .]
}

Comment: You noticed, that you have duplicate property names here? The outer wrapper should be an array instead of an object.

Comment: thanks Jianhong. sorry my question was not clear due to duplicate key. yes it's as you suggested.
{"timestamp1":["id","action"],"timestamp2":["id","action"]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible just use this to create :

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
JSONObject timeObj = new JSONObject();
timeObj.put("UserId", "Action");
obj.put("time", timeObj);
```

and to parse

```
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(value);
JSONObject object=(JSONObject)obj;
JSONObject timeObj = obj.get("time");
String action = timeObj.get("UserId");
```

but I don't recommends you to create JSON with format like that, the JSONObject property key must be unique, I suggest you to use JSONArray instead of JSONObject

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is incorrect. You can't have duplicate `time` keys. Convert it into a JSON array instead.

```
{
  "time": [
    { "UserId": "Action"},
    { "UserId": "Action"},
    { "UserId": "Action"}
  ]
}
```

Here's how you can parse this JSON string

```
String json =
        "{\n" + 
        "  \"time\": [\n" + 
        "    { \"UserId\": \"Action\"},\n" + 
        "    { \"UserId\": \"Action\"}\n" + 
        "  ]\n" + 
        "}";

JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray timeArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("time");

System.out.println(timeArray);
// prints: [{"UserId":"Action"},{"UserId":"Action"}]
```

Here's how you can add a new object to this JSON array

```
timeArray.put(new JSONObject().put("Admin", "CreateUser"));

System.out.println(timeArray);
// prints: [{"UserId":"Action"},{"UserId":"Action"},{"Admin":"CreateUser"}]
```